# How to make changes in only one row in listview generated using BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, getview

I have generated a `ListView` using `BaseAdapter`. I have 2 `Button` in my Listview. I want to make my Button1 invisible when a Button2 in the row is clicked. Then when another row's Button2 is clicked I want to make the Button1 in the current row invisible and the previously invisible Button1 visible i.e at a time only one row's Button1 should be invisible. I have done the following, but I don't know how to set the visibility of the Button1 at the clicked row. Please guide me step by step. My adapter code is as follows:

```
    private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public ListAdapter(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _productlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _productlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    private final boolean[] mHighlightedPositions = new boolean[getCount()];
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
 viewHolder.Button1 = (Button) convertView
    .findViewById(R.id.btn_update);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    viewHolder.Button2 = (Button) convertView
    .findViewById(R.id.btn_update2);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
 viewHolder.Button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 if(mHighlightedPositions[position]) {


                                viewHolder.Button1.setVisibility(convertView.INVISIBLE);     

                    }

            }
        });
        return  convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep hold of the last `hidden Button` view , to make it visible when another item `Button` is clicked.

First, declare a static variable in your `BaseAdapter` to hold the `hidden Button`

```
private static Button lastHiddenButton = null;
```

Next, Add click listener to `Button2` , and hide `Button1` and make the last hidden `Button` visible

```
final Button hideButton = placeHolder.button1;
placeHolder.button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       // if the last hidden button is valid make it to visible
       if(lastHiddenButton != null){
           lastHiddenButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           lastHiddenButton = null;
       }
       // hide button1
       hideButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       lastHiddenButton = hideButton;
        }
    });
```

This will make sure when `Button2` is clicked the `Button1` belongs to the clicked row will be hidden.

With this change , you will note that few other row `Buttons` will also get hidden due to the `ListView` recycle. To fix this you need to inform the `ListView` that all my list item views are different . This will have impact in `ListView` performance when you have `hundreds` of items, but you can't avoid this

Finally , Override the `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount` in `BaseAdapter` and let the `ListView` know that all the items view types are different

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
    // return a unique number
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
}
```